# Condicional de estructuras e impresión de posiciones de memoria

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio: llenar un vector de 15 estructuras cuyos elementos son nombre, apellido y edad, posteriormente utilizando punteros mostrar nombres y apellidos de las personas mayores de edad y las posiciones en memoria de esas estructuras mostradas.

Este es mi código:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <conio.h>
   #include <string.h>

    typedef struct datos {
    char nombre [20];
    char apellido [20];
    short int edad;
    }datos[15];


    void carga (datos *persona, int n);
    void muestra (datos *persona, int n);

    int main() {
    int n;
    datos *persona;

    printf ("Ingrese el tamaño del mismo:\n");
    scanf ("%i",&n);
    persona=(datos *)malloc(n*sizeof(datos));

    carga (persona, n);
    muestra (persona, n);

    free(persona);
    }


    void carga (datos *persona, int n){

    int i=0;

    for (i=0;i<n;i++){

    printf ("Ingrese el Nombre de la Persona:\n");
    fflush (stdin);
    gets (persona[i]->nombre);
    printf ("Ingrese el Apellido:\n");
    gets (persona[i]->apellido);
    printf ("Ingrese su Edad:\n");
    scanf ("%d",&(persona[i])->edad);

}

}

void muestra (datos *persona, int n){
int i;

if (  >18){


for (i=0;i<n;i++){

printf ("Su nombre es:  %s\n",persona[i]->nombre);
printf ("La posicion de memoria del nombre es:  %p",persona);
printf ("Su apellido es:    %s\n",persona[i]->apellido);
printf ("La posicion de memoria del apellido es:    %p",persona);
printf ("Su edad es:    %d\n",persona[i]->edad);
printf("La posicion de memoria de su edad es:   %p",persona);

    }

  }
}
```

Mi duda en este caso seria como expresar la condición para las personas mayores de edad, porque de las formas que quise hacerlo no son correctas porque me aparecía este error:

> ```
> 56    [Warning] comparison between pointer and integer
> ```

y la forma de imprimir las posiciones de memoria tambien quisiera saber como hacerlo para este caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (  >18){
```

¿Qué es exactamente lo que tiene que ser mayor que 18? ¿El día del mes? ¿`n` tal vez? ¿El número de la suerte del usuario? Aquí te falta una variable para poder realizar la comparación.

Claro que si tu idea es que solo se muestren las personas mayores de edad... tendrás que hacer una comparación por cada persona, luego ese `if` debería estar dentro del bucle:

```
for( int i=0; i<n; i++ )
{
    if( persona[i]->edad > 18 )
    {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Adicionalmente, date cuenta que la siguiente declaración:

```
typedef struct datos {
char nombre [20];
char apellido [20];
short int edad;
}datos[15];
```

es, cuanto menos, engorrosa, por varias razones:

- El código no está tabulado, conforme la estructura crezca será más ilegible.
- `typedef` se usa para crear un alias. Crear un alias de un array de tamaño fijo puede complicarte si no lo sabes manejar bien.

Centrándonos en la segunda razón, fíjate en tu código:

```
datos *persona;

printf ("Ingrese el tamaño del mismo:\n");
scanf ("%i",&n);
persona=(datos *)malloc(n*sizeof(datos));
```

Según el alias, `datos` es un array de tamaño 15... luego persona`, que es un puntero a dicho array... resulta que es un **puntero doble**. Si hacemos los reemplazos oportunos el código queda así:

```
struct datos (*persona)[15];

printf ("Ingrese el tamaño del mismo:\n");
scanf ("%i",&n);
persona=(struct datos (*)[15])malloc(n*sizeof(struct datos[15]));
```

Se ve raro, ¿verdad? sobretodo porque estás reservando 15 veces más memoria de la que necesitas realmente. Si hacemos que el alias deje de crear un array el código se simplifica:

```
typedef struct
{
  char nombre [20];
  char apellido [20];
  short int edad;
} datos;
```

Así, el código anterior ahora se corresponde con el siguiente:

```
struct datos *persona;

printf ("Ingrese el tamaño del mismo:\n");
scanf ("%i",&n);
persona=(struct datos *)malloc(n*sizeof(struct datos));
```

Ahora tiene mejor pinta, ¿verdad? E incluso fíjate que podemos declarar las variables justo en el momento de inicializarlas, lo que evita que tengamos variables sin inicializar dando vueltas por el código:

```
datos* persona = (datos*)malloc(n*sizeof(datos));
```

Aparte de esto, como ahora `datos*` ya no es un puntero doble, también hay que actualizar los bucles:

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  printf ("Su nombre es:  %s\n",persona[i].nombre);
  printf ("La posicion de memoria del nombre es:  %p", &persona.nombre);
  printf ("Su apellido es:    %s\n",persona[i].apellido);
  printf ("La posicion de memoria del apellido es:    %p",persona.apellido);
  printf ("Su edad es:    %d\n",persona[i].edad);
  printf("La posicion de memoria de su edad es:   %p",persona.edad);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues muy sencillo, casi lo tienes:

Dentro de la función muestra, en cada vuelta del bucle, compruebas la edad de la persona antes de ejecutar los printf. También, en los printf cuando quieres mostrar las direcciones tienes que hacer cambios. Para los arrays de caracteres, el nombre del array es la dirección de memoria del primer elemento del array, así que lo puedes poner directamente, pero no como lo habías puesto. Y para la edad, al ser un entero, hay que añadirle el operador & para que te muestre la dirección de memoria. El resto del código no lo he revisado.

Algo como esto:

```
void muestra (datos *persona, int n){
     int i;

     for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
         if( persona[i]->edad >= 18) {
             printf ("Su nombre es:  %s\n",persona[i]->nombre);
             printf ("La posicion de memoria del nombre es:  %p",persona[i]->nombre);
             printf ("Su apellido es:    %s\n",persona[i]->apellido);
             printf ("La posicion de memoria del apellido es:    %p",persona[i]->apellido);
             printf ("Su edad es:    %d\n",persona[i]->edad);
             printf("La posicion de memoria de su edad es:   %p",&persona[i]->edad);

          }

      }
  }
```